# Cypher query that aggregate edges of neo4j multigraph and return a simple graph

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, aggregate

We have a multi-graph of email connections. In this graph there are many edges between 2 nodes. Is there any cypher query to aggregate all edges between each node pairs and then return a new graph?

[image]

ATTENTION: I know the query that aggregate edges, but it returns a table, not graph!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To visualize the relationships together you can use apoc's virtual relationships:

```
MATCH (a:Foo)-[r]->(b:Bar)
RETURN a,b, apoc.create.vRelationship(a,'COMBINED',{count:count(*)},b) as rel
```

Comment: It works, but is there any solution without extra plugin?